# Is it possible to print the returned value of a function of different class in case of Anonymous object of scala

Tags: scala, anonymous-objects

I am new to Scala, trying to understand the syntactic behaviors of Scala. I will be really appreciated if anybody help me. Thanks

**With Anonymous Object:** Here in this scenario if I want to print the value of `res`inside the `main` function body then what logic I need to apply?

```
package oops

object AnonymousObject 
{
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit =
  {
    new student().detail(5,9)  // Line 1

  }  
}

class student
{
  def detail(x:Int, y:Int):Int =
  {
    val res = x*y
    println(res)
  }
}
```

**Without Anonymous Object:**
For more information, in this scenario given below, there has no problem to achieve it because of `var s`

```
 class Student
 {  
    var id:Int = 0;  // All fields must be initialized  
    var name:String = null;  
 }  
object MainObject
{  
    def main(args:Array[String])
    {  
        var s = new Student()  // Creating an object  
        println(s.id+" "+s.name);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: In your first case, `class student` does not compile. The method **detail** is annotated to return an Int, so it should just be `x * y` expression in the method body rather than an assignment statement. If you want to print it in **main**, then use `println(new student().detail(5,9))`

Comment: @SamuelHeaney
 Hi, Thanks but unfortunately I tried this `println(new student().detail(5,9))` but it's printed out this `()` instead of `45`

Comment: Rather than doing `def detail(x: Int, y: Int): Unit = val res = x * y`, try `def detail(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x * y`. Currently you are returning Unit, which will print `()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object which has no reference name. So simply you can print like this way inside the `main`

```
object AnonymousObject 
{
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit =
  {
    val res = new student().detail(5,9)
    println(res)

  }  
}

class student
{
  def detail(x:Int, y:Int):Int =
  {
    x*y
  }
}
```

**Output:** `45`